# cobertura graph in hudson

Tags: hudson, code-coverage, plot, cobertura

is there a way to have the [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) test coverage graph be shown on the front page of a project, similar to the test trend graph? I'd like to have that displayed next to the coverage graph. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph does not show up in when running a maven2 project, only a freestyle project.

Comment: appears with version 1.0 of the cobertura plugin, it now does.

Answer (score 5):

Hudson has a set of plugins which you can use to extend its functionality to best suit to your requirements. One of this plugins is the Cobertura Plugin. Once you've installed it, in each of your project's configuration a new Post-Build action will appear with the title 'Publish Cobertura Coverage report'.

With this configuration Hudson is able to build cobertura graphs from a generated report. It's up to you to make your builds generate that report. For this task, if you are using maven, plugins are available to add them to your reports.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for that info. I am at that point and have the graphs generating. I was just trying to figure out if there is a way to get the trend graph to show on the project's main page with the unit test trend graph, rather than having to click into an individual build.

Comment: That's it Jeff, by installing the Cobertura Plugin and mark the corresponding action on post-build actions at your project's configuration the cobertura trend graph will appear at your project's main page, just below the tests one.

Comment: Jeff, have a look through the release notes of the Cobertura plugin (and hudson) as I recall an issue where it wasn't showing the coverage for some reason. I have had issues from time to time where for example it wouldn't show coverage if the build had failed etc.

Comment: Carols, gommo, no such luck here. I do have it enabled in the post build actions, but it doesn't appear on the main page. I have to go into the specific build and then click on coverage report (or into the site documentation).

I'm running hudson 1.309 with cobertura 0.8.8.

Answer (score 1):

Here's posts for

**1.** Setting up a `pom.xml` for generating reports Cobertura, Findbugs, Checkstyle and Surefire unit test results. [development-environment-for-google-app](http://macgyverdev.blogspot.com/2011/04/development-environment-for-google-app.html)

**2.** And how to configure Hudson to display the reports.
[hudson-continous-integration-for-google](http://macgyverdev.blogspot.com/2011/04/hudson-continous-integration-for-google.html)