# can hudson show code coverage with a maven2 project

Tags: maven-2, hudson

So the question is: is there a way to have the cobertura test coverage graph be shown on the front page of a project, similar to the test trend graph, with a maven2 project?

refs: [cobertura graph in hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059115/cobertura-graph-in-hudson)
 [How to generate Cobertura Code Coverage Report using Maven from Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006014/how-to-generate-cobertura-code-coverage-report-using-maven-from-hudson)

If not, is this a bug I should report to them, do you think?

Thanks!
-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hudson Cobertura plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Cobertura+Plugin) should allow a build to be configured with the path to a Cobertura report (in XML format), from which Hudson can then pull the coverage report and render it. The build will still need to run Cobertura itself, either as part of a full **site** generation, or using **cobertura:cobertura**.

From memory, look towards the bottom of the project's configuration page (under Post-Build actions); the setting is labelled something like "Publish Cobertura report".

Comment: yeah, I do run cobertura:cobertura and site.  Your post pointed me in the right direction, though. Upgrading the cobertura plugin from 0.86 to 1.0 seemed to have fixed that problem